# How to call ajax function after browser window close or reload?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

call ajax function after browser window close or reload.
I want to update database table when browser window close or reload.

Comment: You cannot detect the close event in javascript, only the unload.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no way to detect close event in javascript,
We can only detect when the page is unloaded, not when the window is closed.There are onunload & onbeforeunload events which fires whenever the user leaves your page for any reason. So by the use of these event you can know when user leaving the page.

Follow [beforeunload documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Fbeforeunload)

For example

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    //Write your ajax code here
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Your URL',
        data: { "transactionno": transactionNo },
        success: function (data) {                        
            $('#Loader').hide();

        },
        error: function (e) {
            $('#Loader').hide();
        }
    });        
})
```

Comment: where should i call ajax function in above beforeunload function ?